# How to insert form information into html button with php

Tags: php, html

Here's what I'm looking to accomplish. When a user creates a profile they fill out some information with a form. After they submit the form the information is displayed on their profile. One of the form fields is going to be a button that other users can click to do an action. To display the button this is the PHP I currently have:

```
add_action('kleo_bp_after_profile_name', 'my_profile_button');
function my_profile_button()
{
echo '<a href="#" class="success button radius show-for-small" rel="nofollow">Talk</a>';
}
```

I need to input the form information into the href="#" spot. Does anyone know a way around this?

Thanks.

Comment: if i understand you correctly then you will need to use javascript for that

Comment: Use jQuery to solve this

Comment: Hard to understand what you have and what you're trying to do. How do you put information into a button? What are you actually trying to accomplish? Submit the information to a server?

Comment: The `href='#'` of what?

Comment: what's wrong with a standard html form approach?

Comment: Sorry I'll try to explain what I'm trying to do better. I have a form that users have to fill out after they create a profile. On their profile page there is a button (Example is <a href="#" class="success button radius show-for-small" rel="nofollow">Some Text</a>

Comment: Oops...hit enter haha. Then in the html the form information is displayed in the href="#" spot.

Comment: Please edit your question instead.

Comment: still don't see why you can't use the normal form approach

Comment: Also, `<a href="#" class="success button radius show-for-small" rel="nofollow">Some Text</a>` is a _link_, not a button

Comment: Question has been edited. Thanks guys.

Comment: Is this wordpress or cake?

Comment: I'm creating the website in WordPress.

Comment: I have a bad habit of calling links buttons. My bad...it displays as a button but I actually need to change the link.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to simply submit a form that a user fills out.  If that is the case, you can't use a link, but you need to use a button:

```
<form action="submitpage.php" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="Some Text" />
</form>
```

or

```
<form action="submitpage.php" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" />
    <button type="submit" class="success button radius show-for-small">Some Text</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, if you have captured that information with a POST variable, named 'redirect' for example, you could use it to generate a button. The problem is that I don't understand very well what you mean with *be put into href="#" spot*, because buttons don't have that property, so I write you the code to use it on a redirection which is done at clicking the button:

```
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="location.href='<?php echo $_POST["redirect"];?>';">
```

If you want to use information in a link, which actually have *href* property use this:

```
<a id="link" href="<?php echo $_POST['redirect'];?>">Text of the link</a>
```